# UDP server getting data from client even if server is started last

Tags: java, udp

I am currently studying for a programming exam and in an earlier exam set one question has the following code.

```
public class Question18 {
public static class Question18Server implements Runnable {

    DatagramSocket serverSocket;
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
    byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

    public Question18Server(int port) throws SocketException{
        serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    }
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new
                    DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                    receiveData.length);
            try {
                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
                System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
public static class Question18Client implements Runnable {
    int port;
    DatagramSocket clientSocket;
    InetAddress IPAddress;
    public Question18Client(int port) throws SocketException,
            UnknownHostException {
        this.port = port;
        clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
        IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
    }
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            String sentence = "Hello " + i * 2;
            sendData = sentence.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,
                    sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
            try {
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        Thread server = new Thread(new Question18Server(9000));
        Thread client = new Thread(new Question18Client(9000));

        server.start();
        client.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
  }
}
```

The question that im having trouble with is this:

**What would be the output if server.start() and client.start() are inverted?**

I dont have much experience with UDP and i might have misunderstood something but my initial thought was that the server might receive some of the datagramPackets send by the client.

But to my surprise it received all the data send.

i tried changing the code to the following to create a small pause between the start of the two threads, but it is still working.

```
        client.start();            
        long waittime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000;
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() < waittime)
        {}            
        server.start();
```

I really hope someone can explain why this is working, my current theories are

a) That the data is stored on my computer due to the fact that im using "localhost"

b) that the DatagramPackets search for the right IP and Port for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no connection setup is required in UDP, the startup order of *publisher* and *subscriber* is less important than in TCP. In UDP, a late subscriber won't necessarily see all packets, and there is no guarantee even if the subscriber wasn't late.

In your code, `Question18Client` is the *publisher* and `Question18Server` is the *subscriber*. Try the following experiment:

1. start publisher
2. send 1024 packets with an incrementing integer as content
3. start subscriber
4. send another 1024 with an incrementing integer as content

For example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class SoQuestion {
    private static class Publisher {
        private DatagramSocket socket;
        private InetAddress address;
        private int port;

        private int count = 1;

        public Publisher(int port, String host) 
            throws SocketException, UnknownHostException {
            this.port = port;
            address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
        }

        public void publish(int packets) {
            System.out.println(
                "Publishing " + packets + 
                " packets via UDP to port " + this.port
                );

            for (int i = 1; i <= packets; i++,count++) {

                String data = "" + count;
                byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes();

                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                    dataBytes,
                    dataBytes.length,
                    address,
                    port
                    );

                try {
                    socket.send(packet);
                    System.out.println(data + " sent");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Subscriber extends Thread {

        private int port;
        private String host;

        private InetAddress address;
        private DatagramSocket socket;

        private byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*1024];
        private volatile boolean finished;

        public Subscriber(int port, String host) throws SocketException{
            this.port = port;
            this.host = host;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                socket = new DatagramSocket(port, address);
                socket.setSoTimeout(5000);

                System.out.println("Subscribed via UDP to port " + port);
                while (!finished) {

                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                        buffer,
                        buffer.length
                        );

                    socket.receive(packet);
                    System.out.println(
                        new String(
                            packet.getData(), 
                            0, 
                            packet.getLength()
                            ) + " received"
                        );

                }

                System.out.println("Subscription finished");
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException x ) {
                System.out.println("Subscription timed-out.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void finish() {
            this.finished = true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int packets = 1024;

            Publisher publisher = new Publisher(9000, "localhost");
            publisher.publish(packets);

            Subscriber subscriber = new Subscriber(9000, "localhost");
            subscriber.start();

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            publisher.publish(packets);

            //subscriber.finish();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this with:

```
javac SoQuestion.java
java SoQuestion|sort -k 1,1n -k 2,2r
```

I see no receives for the first 1024 packets and matching receives for the next 1024 on `x64 Linux 3.16.7-29`:

```
1 sent
...
1024 sent
1025 sent
1025 received
...
2048 sent
2048 received
```

Comment: I must admit that im very confused at this point.
If i send 1024 packets first and then start the server and send another 1024 packets i get output that says something like this:
Recieved: 0
...
Recieved: 1023

This seems normal but then i get values ranging from 0023 to 9993
I guess i has something to do with the binary values getting messed up, but im not sure

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, @Witten: are you getting `Received: 0023`..`Received: 9993`, after getting `Received: 0`..`Received: 1023`? I'd expect for you to see `Received: 1024`..`Received: 2047` and some number of the packets in the 0-1023 range; but, if your code is correct you should not see any packets above 2047...

Comment: @Witten -- does this answer address your question(s)? If so, please upvote&select the answer; if not, please add more details.

Comment: Think there was something wrong with my computer or the code, because it executed fine on other computers. But thanks for you help, i greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a DatagramSocket to send data does not require a listener on the other side.  The data just doesn't go anywhere.  It's also not stored anywhere waiting for a listener socket to open.  The behaviour you are seeing is most likely caused by your code.

You should really do something with the exceptions that you are catching instead of ignoring them.

You should also make sure to stop your Question18Server. The ServerSocket is in in receive() and not closed.

Do you really need to use a thread for the client? Can't you just run this as part of your main class without starting a thread.

I think if you address these issues you'll start to see what's really happening.